# Powershell add text to files if does not exist

Tags: powershell, text

I would like to create a Powershell script that adds text to *.jsp *.sh *.cmd files. I would also like it to check if the text already exist in that file and if it does then it skips the file. So far I have found Select-String which will find the text in the file. How do I then use this information to add text to top of the files that do not have the text in them? I also found Add-Content which seems to add the content I want but I would like to do it at the beginning and have some logic to not just keep re-adding it every time I run the ps1.

```
Select-String -Pattern "TextThatIsInMyFile" -Path c:\Stuff\batch\*.txt

Add-Content -Path "c:\Stuff\batch\*.txt" -Value "`r`nThis is the last line"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very similar to what @MikeWise has, but a little better optimized. I have it pulling the data and making the provider filter the files returned (much better than filtering afterwards). Then I pass it to a `Where` statement using `Select-String`'s `-quiet` parameter to provide boolean $true/$false to the Where. That way only file that you want to look at are even looked at, and only those missing the text you need are altered.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Stuff\Batch\*" -Include *.jsp,*.sh,*.cmd -File | 
    Where{!(Select-String -SimpleMatch "TextThatIsInMyFile" -Path $_.fullname -Quiet)} |
    ForEach{
        $Path = $_.FullName
        "TextThatIsInMyFile",(Get-Content $Path)|Set-Content $Path
    }
```

**Edit:** As you discovered the `\*` does not work with `-Recursive`. Use the following if you need to recurse:

```
    Get-ChildItem "C:\Stuff\Batch" -Include *.jsp,*.sh,*.cmd -File -Recurse
```

Comment: One question I do have is how do you make this search through all the folders in the directory?

Comment: I tried using Get-ChildItem -Recurse but that does not seem to change anything.

Comment: I figured it out, if you do \* as your path -recursuive does not work. I changed it back and now it is good. 'Get-ChildItem "C:\Stuff\Batch\" -Recurse -Include *.jsp,*.sh,*.cmd,*.txt -File |'

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond, just got in to work for the week. Glad you got it working for your needs, and I did update the answer to reflect your findings for future answer seekers.

Comment: I had to alter multiple .gitignore files. So if you are dealing with hidden files add the -hidden and -force flag to Get-ChildItem.

Answer (score 2):

Refering to the manual: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx

Specifically:

Outputs

The output type is the type of the objects that the cmdlet emits.
• Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo or System.Boolean 
By default, the output is a set of MatchInfo objects, one for each match    found. 
If you use the **Quiet** parameter, the output is a **Boolean value** indicating whether the pattern was found.

I also think that you also need to do this per file. So (presumbably):

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Stuff\batch" -Filter *.txt 
for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) 
{ 
  $filename = $files[$i].FullName        
  $b =  Select-String -Quiet -Pattern "TextThatIsInMyFile" -Path $fileName

   if (-not $b)
   {
      Add-Content -Path $fileName -Value "`r`nTextThatIsInMyFile"
   }
}
```

I tested this and I think it does what you want, i.e. adds the text to the end of files that do not have it, and not doing it more than once.