# PowerShell in Batch hybrid - How to find several different strings in a txt and append to the top only if it does not exist?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, hybrid

This is my attempt at learning PowerShell. No edu background in coding/scripting. Only learned Batch by reading different examples here in StackOverflow and Superuser, trying to adapt found snippets to what is needed, and a lot of trial and error. Please be kind!

There are several strings (without the numbering) that needs to be added to a txt file sequentially and to the top of the file:

1. [/This/IsJust.AnExample]
2. IsThisTrue=False
3. IsThisFalse=

I attempted to "convert" what was [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28511082/11432377) to something that *might* look usable in a Batchfile:

```
start "" /wait /min powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-ChildItem 'D:\Sample Path\%sample_var%\Sample file.txt' -File -recurse | Where{!(Select-String -SimpleMatch '([/This/IsJust.AnExample])|(IsThisTrue=False)|(IsThisFalse=)' -Path $_.fullname -Quiet)} | ForEach{ $Path = $_.FullName '([/This/IsJust.AnExample])|(IsThisTrue=False)|(IsThisFalse=)',(Get-Content $Path) | Set-Content $Path })"
```

Expectation:

1. Look for each string. If it doesn't exist, add it

- The string(s) must only be added if they/it do(es) not exist

Example: If it's entirely missing

```
[/MoreRandom /Example/In /Here]
MaybeThisIsCorrect=False
MaybeIAmConfused=True
MaybeINeedToLearnTheBasicsOfPowershell=True
MyEnglishIsTerrible=True
Apologetic=True
```

Expected:

```
[/This/IsJust.AnExample]
IsThisTrue=False
IsThisFalse=

[/MoreRandom /Example/In /Here]
MaybeThisIsCorrect=False
MaybeIAmConfused=True
MaybeINeedToLearnTheBasicsOfPowershell=True
MyEnglishIsTerrible=True
Apologetic=True
```

- The string(s) must be always added to the top of the file in the order they were written in and reordered if they were found in other lines

Example:

```
<newline/blank>
<last string>
<newline/blank>
<string1>
<newline/blank>
<existing content>
```

Expected:

```
<string1>
<string2>
<last string>
<newline/blank>
<existing content>
```

- The top of the page must not have any spaces or blanks

Example:

```
<newline/blank>
<newline/blank>
<newline/blank>
<string1>
<last string>
<string2>
<newline/blank>
<existing content>
```

Expected:

```
<string1>
<string2>
<last string>
<newline/blank>
<existing content>
```

- The last string added must have a blank after to separate it from the existing content
  Example:

```
<last string>
<newline/blank>
<existing content starts here>
```

2. All must be inline, no external files such as .ps1, .bat, .txt, etc.
3. It doesn't need an -include since it's only searching in a specific file.
4. Must be usable in a batchfile because it's gonna be added to a for loop.
5. Always able to handle spaces in file paths
6. Must be able to handle encoding with BOM (some snippets added random non-Latin characters)

Result of original attempt:

- It just fails without doing anything to the txt.

Result of attempts after receiving suggestions/info:

- `start "" /wait /min powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-ChildItem 'example.txt' -File -recurse -PipelineVariable FilePath | Where{!(Select-String -SimpleMatch '([/This/IsJust.AnExample])|(IsThisTrue=False)|(IsThisFalse=)' -Path $_.fullname -Quiet)} | ForEach{ [string[]]$ToAdd = [string]::Empty; $Out = Get-Content $FilePath -raw; Switch ($Out){{$_ -notmatch [regex]::Escape('[/This/IsJust.AnExample]')}{$ToAdd += '[/This/IsJust.AnExample]'};{$_ -notmatch 'IsThisTrue=False'}{$ToAdd += 'IsThisTrue=False'};{$_ -notmatch 'IsThisFalse='}{$ToAdd += 'IsThisFalse='}};$ToAdd,$Out | Set-Content -Path $FilePath})"` - works but it always adds the missing string on the top of the page not in the order they were written in. It also does not add a blank (separator) in between the last string and the first line of the existing content.
- `'([/This/IsJust.AnExample])|(IsThisTrue=False)|(IsThisFalse=)'` - Adds a single line instead of checking each string if it exists
- `('[/This/IsJust.AnExample]','IsThisTrue=False','IsThisFalse=')` - Adds all strings only if all of them of are missing. If there is a single string already present, it won't add the remaining.

Notes:

- After further digging, the file was found out to be encoded as UTF-16 LE BOM
- The file paths are always with spaces
- Added the missing closing parenthesis causing the snippet to crash
- Changed `-NoP -Ex -By -c` to `-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command` as suggested by @Compo

<s>What is causing it to fail and</s> how to properly do it?

A link to a dummies guide on how to convert PowerShell to Batch would also be nice.

Additionally, would appreciate to know which part can be reused in order to add more strings if needed in the future.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to run multiple commands inside the `ForEach` loop without separating them at all, or at least not properly.

Comment: Now explain to us the purpose of `start "" /wait /min powershell.exe ...`, and whether you tried without the `start` command; i.e. `@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe ...`.

Comment: @vav, it's definitely an _aside_, but note that: `-Ex -By` couldn't have _worked_ for you; instead, because it was _quietly ignored_ (which should be considered a [_bug_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20449)) it happened _not to get in the way_, namely in CLI invocations that happen not to involve calls to _script files_ (`*.ps1` and similar).

Comment: @Compo Thanks to your hint to check without `start "" /wait /min`. One of the reasons it was failing was missing a closing parenthesis.

@TheMadTechnician Thanks for letting me know it wasn't being separated properly. I managed to fix it by changing to `('[/This/IsJust.AnExample]','IsThisTrue=False','IsThisFalse=')` as well as adding the semi-colon after the first command.

Comment: Good point, @Compo, but there's one additional aspect: Due to `/min`, the output from the PowerShell CLI call is effectively hidden. To achieve the same effect with direct invocation, you'd need `powershell ... >NUL 2>&1`

Comment: @mklement0 Noted the shorthand must not be used.

Comment: @vav, to be clear: The `-ex` part works, because, as a parameter _name_ prefix, due to PowerShell's "elastic syntax",  it unambiguously identifies the `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter (that said, in _scripts_, this is best avoided in the interest of both readability and long-term stability). By contrast, the "elastic syntax" does _not_ apply to parameter _values_ (aka _arguments_), which is why a `by` argument (leaving the inappropriate `-` prefix aside) _cannot work_ as an attempt to refer to `Bypass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm... If you want that the solution works in a Batch file, why not write it in a Batch file in first place? Besides, IMHO the Batch solution is simpler than the PowerShell one and it runs *much faster* than the PS one, specially if you want to run it in a loop...

**EDIT 2023/10/16**: Code modified as requested in comments...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the strings that needs to be reviewed
set "n=0"
set "strings="
for %%a in (
   "[/This/IsJust.AnExample]"
   "IsThisTrue=False"
   "IsThisFalse="
   ) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "string[!n!]=%%~a"
   set "strings=!strings!/C:"%%~a" "
)

rem Get the line number of the first line of "existing content"
set "skip="
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /V /L %strings% test.txt') do (
   if not defined skip if "%%b" neq "" set /A "skip=%%a-1"
)
if defined skip (
   if "%skip%" neq "0" (
      set "skip=skip=%skip%"
   ) else (
      set "skip="
   )
)

rem Insert the strings at beginning of output file
(
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo !string[%%i]!
echo/
for /F "%skip% delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do echo %%a
) > output.txt

rem Last step: update input file
REM move /Y output.txt test.txt
```

If you want to run this code in a loop you could directly insert it in the loop, or you can convert it into a subroutine (adding a `:label` at beginning and an `exit /B` at end) and `call :label` in the loop

PS - You said you need this code run in a `for` loop, but you don't specify *which* value will be modified in the loop... If you do so, we could write the complete solution

**EDIT 2023/10/17** *New code added because there are A LOT of changes!*

This question have been modified several times with *new* specifications each time it is modified. Let's review your examples and descriptions so far:

- In the first example, the input have not anyone of the strings. The expected result is OK.
- In the second example the input have strings at beginning in different order and then the `<existing content>`. It does NOT specify that a string could be in the `<existing content>`
- In the third example the input have strings and blank lines at beginning and then the `<existing content>` Again, it does NOT specify that a string could be in the `<existing content>`
- The fourth example is even clearer: after the `<last string>` the result must contain a `<newline/blank>` and then **`<existing content starts here>`** What this "existing content" is? The contents of the input file *below* the strings (as specified). You *never* specified that THE EXISTING CONTENT OF THE INPUT FILE COULD INCLUDE A STRING!!! If the "existing content" have a string, then it MUST BE MODIFIED (by removing such a string) when it is passed to the result file. In such a case, it can't be longer called **EXISTING** CONTENT!!!!!  In other words: if you called it "existing content", then you used a term opposite to the desired result (so it is a term that generates confusion, instead of being descriptive)...
- In your comments you reaffirm *the same specifications*: In example #3 if D E F exists in the file, insert A B C (space) at beginning. Ok. In example #4 B C D E F exists, that is, the "existing content" is D E F and this content have NOT a string!
- Finally, in your **last comment**, you say that my code *"keeps adding the strings in the file even if they exist"*. This can only happen if the strings exists IN THE EXISTING CONTENTS, that is, in any line below the strings that appear at beginning of the file. In other words: if input is D C E B F you want as output A B C (blank) D E F, but my program generates A B C (blank) D C E B F, right? Why you didn't said THAT!

You have explained A LOT of things, but not the important ones...

You *should* help us to help you, not hide important information that makes it difficult to help you... **`:(`**

I hope the new code below solve you problem (at least, the last one)...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the strings that needs to be reviewed
set "n=0"
set "strings="
for %%a in (
   "[/This/IsJust.AnExample]"
   "IsThisTrue=False"
   "IsThisFalse="
   ) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "string[!n!]=%%~a"
   set "strings=!strings!/C:"%%~a" "
)

rem Generate the output file:
(
rem First, insert the strings at beginning
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo !string[%%i]!
echo/
rem Then, insert the lines in the file that have NOT the strings
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /V /L %strings% test.txt') do echo %%a
) > output.txt

rem Last step: update input file
REM move /Y output.txt test.txt
```

**LAST CODE:** *I give up...*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the strings that needs to be reviewed
set "n=0"
set "strings="
for %%a in (
   "[/This/IsJust.AnExample]"
   "IsThisTrue=False"
   "IsThisFalse="
   ) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "string[!n!]=%%~a"
   set "strings=!strings!/C:"%%~a" "
)

rem Process files with .ini extension
for %%f in (*.ini) do (

   rem Generate the output file:
   (
   rem First, insert the strings at beginning
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo !string[%%i]!
   echo/
   rem Then, insert the lines in the file that have NOT the strings
   rem Convert a UTF-16 LE BOM file to UTF-8 via TYPE command
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%%f" ^| findstr /V /L %strings%') do echo %%a
   ) > output.txt

   rem Last step: update input file
   move /Y output.txt "%%f" > NUL

)
```

Comment: removing the last REM (from ```move /Y output.txt test.txt```) replaces the original content of the file instead of appending to it. How to make it only append?

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow you... I tested your examples 1 and 2. In both cases my program generates the _exact same_ "expected result" you posted above, excepting in an empty line that you added to example #1 (but _not_ to example #2. Why?). I don't understand what you want

Comment: Your script replaces the file, therefore, the previous content gets deleted.

example #3 -  A B C (blank) are to be appended if the string does not exist while D E F exists in the file.

before running script:

D
E
F

the desired output:

A
B
C
(blank)
D
E
F

example #4 - B C D E F exists, A B C (space) are to be appended if the string does not exist.

before running the script:
B
C
D
E
F

desired output:
A
B
C
(blank)
D
E
F

Comment: Wow! These are _a lot_ of **new** requirements that you don't listed in the first version of your question! Check my new solution...

Comment: It was already there but I added more examples and tried to expound because of the confusion. Your latest update keeps adding the strings in the file even if they exist. Therefore, if they were run thrice, the strings are added thrice. I need the strings to be added in the order they were written in (if the lines are further down, they must be reordered) with the first string at the top and adding the next strings sequentially, without duplicates, without a blank on the top of the page, with a blank between the last string to be added and the existing contents of the file to separate them.

Comment: I wish I could help but I'm still learning and your approach is news to me. Can you also explain the what the following ```set /A n+=1```, ```set "string[!n!]=%%~a"```, ```set "strings=!strings!/C:"%%~a```, ```set /A "skip=%%a-1"```, ```(1,1,%n%)```, ```!string[%%i]!``` do? This is the first time I've seen those.

Comment: The `set "string[!n!]=%%~a"` is the definition of an [array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990). See my last (**2023/10/17**) edit in my code... **`:(`**

Comment: Thanks for doing a thorough review. I'm certain it's something I need to work on. To be fair, I was told on a different post that I should present a minimal example so that's what I tried to do here but it seems to have caused a lot more confusion due to some important things that were left out unintentionally. The latest update works on its own (not in a for loop or subroutine) IF the file encoding is changed to UTF-8. If it's in a subroutine or added inside the for loop, it still overwrites the file regardless. The path does contain spaces if it helps. Copying & moving did the trick.

Comment: I edited your post but sth is wrong w/ `"for /F "%skip% delims=" %%a in (%in%) do echo %%a ) >> "%out%"` & I guess it's one of the reasons it failed. Paths are w/ spaces and its vars were set from within the for loop. If %in% is surrounded with double quotes, it prints the path onto the file which is unintended. If it's without double quotes, it fails & just proceeds but I believe it affects how it appends %in% to %out% & the reason it looks like it overwrites %in% instead of append. I'll mark this as the answer as soon as you're able to fix it without having to rely on the copy line I added.

Comment: **1.** My last code, the working one, have not any `%skip%` part. **2.** I have no idea of what you are talking about about code I can't see! **3.** In my answer, I asked you: _"If you specify which value will be modified in the `for` loop, we could write the complete solution."_ That is, something like: "Process all files in current folder with .xyz extension". You have _not_ answered that point yet... **4.** I strongly recommend you that carefully read [this post](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6108). **5.** IMHO you need my help more than I need your rep points.  **`:(`**

Comment: OMG I'm such an idiot! You're absolutely right; I need your help *badly..* I didn't realize I copied the older one. That latest update works almost perfectly if not for the BOM encoding which I found out much later to have been causing issues. TYSM!!! I revised my edit to just include the powershell snippet to change the file's encoding.

Comment: 2. It's still under review. 3. It's just a single Game.ini file for a Steam game and its path has spaces. Again, your latest edit works if the file's encoding is changed to UTF-8, otherwise, it will overwrite Game.ini with the strings plus non-standard chars removing the previous content 4. I understand that I need to provide as much info. Will do that in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: See my **LAST CODE**   **`:(`**

Answer (score 2):

This may be wrong, but it seems to be what you are asking.

```
$TargetFile = '.\Sample file.txt'
$OutputFile = '.\Sample file updated.txt'
# Create an array of the strings to look for.
# This could easily be read from a file and contain hundreds of strings.
$Patterns = @(
    '[/This/IsJust.AnExample]'
    'IsThisTrue=False'
    'IsThisFalse='
)
# Create a hash to identify if each of the patterns is found.
$TrackingHash = @{}
foreach ($Pattern in $Patterns) {
    $TrackingHash[$Pattern] = $false
}
# Examine the file and indicate if a string from the array is ever found.
# If it is found, it will not be added to the top of the output file.
Get-Content -Path $TargetFile |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -in $Patterns) { $TrackingHash[$_] = $true }
    }
# Iterate over the hash. Add any line that was not found to the LinesToAdd array.
$LinesToAdd = @()
foreach ($h in $TrackingHash.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Verbose "$($h.Name): $($h.Value)"
    if ($h.Value -eq $false) {
        $LinesToAdd += $h.Name
    }
}
# Write the output file containing the LinesToAdd followed by the original target file content.
$LinesToAdd + (Get-Content $TargetFile) | Set-Content -Path $OutputFile
```

UPDATE:

Store the script above in a file such as Find-StringsInFile.ps1.
In a cmd.exe .bat file script, run it with PowerShell Core.

```
pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -File '.\Find-StringsInFile.ps1'
```

If you are on the older Windows PowerShell, use:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File '.\Find-StringsInFile.ps1'
```

To be more useful, the PowerShell script should have parameters. That is what you would want if you want to use this "inside a batch for loop" .bat file script.

Comment: How do I add this inside a batch for loop?

Comment: Why are the strings added in random order? Can it be made to append in the order they were written in? Is there a way to make this directly edit the file instead of using input/output files? Any hints on how to break them apart to be run within ```powershell.exe "()"``` to avoid using another external file (.ps1 in this case)? My post had been updated with additional info and examples.

Answer (score 1):

You are running separate commands within your `ForEach-Object` loop, but you don't denote that they're separate. Here, this bit:

```
|ForEach{ $Path = $_.FullName '([/This/IsJust.AnExample])|(IsThisTrue=False)|(IsThisFalse=)',(Get-Content $Path) | Set-Content $Path }
```

If that were in a script with some decent formatting would look something like this:

```
| ForEach-Object {
    $Path = $_.FullName
    '([/This/IsJust.AnExample])|(IsThisTrue=False)|(IsThisFalse=)',(Get-Content $Path) | Set-Content $Path
  }
```

So that's two commands within the `ForEach`. If you want to jam them both onto one line you need a semicolon to denote the end of one command, and the start of another. So in that one-liner you have you need to put a semicolon after `$Path = $_.FullName` so your entire line looks like this:

```
start "" /wait /min powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-ChildItem 'D:\Sample Path\%sample_var%\Sample file.txt' -File -recurse | Where{!(Select-String -SimpleMatch '([/This/IsJust.AnExample])|(IsThisTrue=False)|(IsThisFalse=)' -Path $_.fullname -Quiet)} | ForEach{ $Path = $_.FullName; '([/This/IsJust.AnExample])|(IsThisTrue=False)|(IsThisFalse=)',(Get-Content $Path) | Set-Content $Path }"
```

Now, that won't really do what you want it to I don't think, it'll just add that one line to the top of your file, but it will at least make your one-liner do *something*.

Ok, to check each string there's a few ways to do it, but I prefer the `switch` cmdlet rather than a series of `if` statements. Long hand it would look something like this, we'll jam it into one line after:

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\Sample Path\%sample_var%\Sample file.txt' -File -recurse -PipelineVariable FilePath | 
    Where{!(Select-String -SimpleMatch '([/This/IsJust.AnExample])|(IsThisTrue=False)|(IsThisFalse=)' -Path $_.fullname -Quiet)} | 
    ForEach{ 
        [string[]]$ToAdd = [string]::Empty
        $Out = Get-Content $FilePath -raw
        Switch ($Out){
            {$_ -notmatch '[/This/IsJust.AnExample]'} {$ToAdd += '[/This/IsJust.AnExample]'}
            {$_ -notmatch 'IsThisTrue=False'}         {$ToAdd += 'IsThisTrue=False'}
            {$_ -notmatch 'IsThisFalse='}             {$ToAdd += 'IsThisFalse='}
        }
        $ToAdd,$Out | Set-Content -Path $FilePath
        }
```

Then you just add a semicolon to the end of each line and remove the whitespace. Looks horrid, but works the same:

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\Sample Path\%sample_var%\Sample file.txt' -File -recurse -PipelineVariable FilePath | Where{!(Select-String -SimpleMatch '([/This/IsJust.AnExample])|(IsThisTrue=False)|(IsThisFalse=)' -Path $_.fullname -Quiet)} | ForEach{ [string[]]$ToAdd = [string]::Empty; $Out = Get-Content $FilePath -raw; Switch ($Out){{$_ -notmatch '[/This/IsJust.AnExample]'}{$ToAdd += '[/This/IsJust.AnExample]'};{$_ -notmatch 'IsThisTrue=False'}{$ToAdd += 'IsThisTrue=False'};{$_ -notmatch 'IsThisFalse='}{$ToAdd += 'IsThisFalse='}};$ToAdd,$Out | Set-Content -Path $FilePath}
```

**Edit:** Ok, so you just need to ensure that all three lines are there in order at the top of each file. In that case you may as well strip the any of the three lines that do exist out of the file and inject them at the top.

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\Sample Path\%sample_var%\Sample file.txt' -File -recurse -PipelineVariable FilePath |
    ForEach-Object -Begin {$Header = "[/This/IsJust.AnExample]`nIsThisTrue=False`nIsThisFalse="} -Process {
        $RawText = (Get-Content $FilePath -Raw) -replace '(?ms)^(\[/This/IsJust\.AnExample\]|IsThisTrue=False|IsThisFalse=)\r?\n'
        $Header,$RawText -join "`n"| Set-Content -Path $FilePath
        }
```

That way regardless of if it is missing none, or all three of those header lines, it will remove any and then place them all in order. Here it is shortened up and made into one line:

```
GCI 'D:\Sample Path\%sample_var%\Sample file.txt' -File -r -Pi FP |% -B {$H = "[/This/IsJust.AnExample]`nIsThisTrue=False`nIsThisFalse="} -P {$RT=(GC $FP -Ra) -replace '(?ms)^(\[/This/IsJust\.AnExample\]|IsThisTrue=False|IsThisFalse=)\r?\n';$H,$RT -join "`n"| SC -Pat $FP}
```

Comment: You're right. It's missing the closing parenthesis and the above is not what I want to do. `('[/This/IsJust.AnExample]','IsThisTrue=False','IsThisFalse=')` works but if one of the values is already in the txt, it doesn't touch the txt. Would like for it to check each value  and if it doesn't exist, add it to the txt.

Comment: So you want it to include all 3 strings? Check each one, and if it is missing add that string. Right?

Comment: Correct. Is that doable?

Comment: It is. I'm short on time right now, but I'll try and update my answer tomorrow. It's going to be hard to fit it all in one line though.

Comment: That'd be nice if you can, please. It's gonna be inserted in a batch for loop and I'm unfamiliar with PowerShell. I've also updated the post to hopefully further clarify what is needed and also added some examples.

Comment: The new update didn't add the first line and also the two lines weren't on their own lines as in the example. Tried adding 'n'r (backticks not apostrophes) but it just added the last 2 strings to the output instead of placing the next string on the next line. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, to be fair your first line is not valid regex, which is why it probably fails. if you change it to `-notmatch [regex]::Escape('[/This/IsJust.AnExample]')` it'll work. I'm not able to replicate the other issue. Did you miss the `[string[]]` declaration?

Comment: Hey ```-notmatch [regex]::Escape('[/This/IsJust.AnExample]')``` worked, thank you very much. If I remove the 2nd line or 3rd line to test if it adds them in right order, the 2nd or 3rd line is added to the top. Perhaps, I should have been more clearer that they should always be in the correct order? The strings are unique, therefore, it's okay to re-arrange them to be in the order they were written in the script if somehow some of the strings ended up in other lines in the file. I hope it made sense. Apologies as English is not my native language, I'm struggling to fully explain what is needed

Comment: That changes this whole thing. In that case it should be that if the file is missing any of them remove all of them and add the whole set at the top of the file.

Comment: Is that complicated? Basically, they will always look like: <top of the page, no newline/space/blank here at all><string1><newline><string2><newline><string3><newline><newline><existing content>. There's always a blank space in between the last added string and the first line of the existing content to separate them if that makes sense.

Comment: Exact code: ``@echo off
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(GCI 'Game.ini' -File -r -Pi FP |% -B {$H = "[/This/IsJust.AnExample]`nIsThisTrue=False`nIsThisFalse="} -P {$RT=(GC $FP -Ra) -replace '(?ms)^(\[/This/IsJust\.AnExample\]|IsThisTrue=False|IsThisFalse=)\r?\n';$H,$RT -join "`n"| SC -Pat $FP})"
pause>nul``
Short ver. threw a bunch of errors: 
`At line:1 char:45 = Missing type name after '['.`
`At line:1 char:217 = You must provide a value expression following the '-join' operator.`
``At line:1 char:218 = Unexpected token '`n' in expression or statement.``

Comment: I did a bit of searching and escaping worked: ``"""[/This/IsJust.AnExample]`nIsThisTrue=False`nIsThisFalse="""`` and ``"""`n""""`` but the blank line in between the last string and the first line of the old content is missing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, just add another new line after the initial strings: `"""[/This/IsJust.AnExample]\`nIsThisTrue=False\`nIsThisFalse=\`n"""`

Comment: Forgot to mention I tried it but it adds a space under the last string every time the batch is run. How to ensure it only adds a single line after the last string no matter how many times it's run?

Comment: You could clear the whitespace from the original file, or just the start of it if you want. `$H,$RT.TrimStart() -join "\`n"` or `$H,$RT.Trim() -join "\`n"`